# polygon tool in Eagle PCB

Tags: eaglecad, pcb-layers, ground-plane

The polygon tool can be used to create power planes. This is the common use of it and I am not aware of any other application of it.

When power plane is created, we name the plane to have same signal name as the ground signal. Once the plane is drawn and we click rat's nest, the signal paths are made distinct from the plane by removing the copper around edges of the signal trace. The copper plane swamps any signals with same name as the plane itself.

I have 1 question:

If I create two small planes and then a big plan that then overlaps both of them, how do I keep them seperate? What I want to achieve is below. The blue color is copper. There are two small planes inside a big plane. I don't know how to achieve the white seperation. It seems that pressing rat's nest does make signal trace distinct from power but not overlapping planes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The planes have a so called `rank` setting.

Planes with a higher rank (like in sports, 1 is ranked higher than 2) will take priority and be filled first. Lower rank planes will automatically cut themselves out around the higher ranked planes. The clearance will be the larger of the two isolate settings (if one plane has an isolate of 12mil, and the other 24mil, a 24mil gap will result).

Comment: your solution has worked but there is 1 problem. Isolate seems to control the distance between a trace and the surrounding plane but not between planes. If I have 2 planes that overlap and copper is cut to distinguish them, the distance created between them is not being controlled via the "isolate" field. How do I increase the distance as DRC is generating error?

Comment: @quantum231 it means you have given them the same rank. Overlapping polygons on different nets needs to be given a different rank.